# Oracle - MINUS-operator with different results than OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, outer-join

In Oracle the following MINUS SQL statement returns results, while the allegedly equivalent OUTER JOIN statement doesn't return any.

Results:

```
SELECT
  /*+parallel (8)*/
  pd.item_id
FROM MY_TABLE@DB_LINK_PROD_ENV
WHERE pd.valid_to='09.09.9999'
MINUS
SELECT
  /*+parallel (8)*/
  it.item_id
FROM MY_TABLE@DB_LINK_TEST_ENV
WHERE it.valid_to='09.09.9999' ;
```

No results:

```
SELECT
  /*+parallel (8)*/
  pd.item_id,
  it.item_id
FROM MY_TABLE@DB_LINK_PROD_ENV
LEFT OUTER JOIN MY_TABLE@DB_LINK_TEST_ENV
ON pd.item_id     = it.item_id
WHERE it.valid_to ='09.09.9999'
AND pd.valid_to   ='09.09.9999'
AND it.item_id   IS NULL;
```

Without knowing the data, what could be the reason?

Comment: Where you say "intersect" don't you mean "minus"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first query it is `MINUS`. Means it will show all `item_id` present in DB_LINK_PROD_ENV having valid_to='09.09.9999' but not present in DB_LINK_TEST_ENV having valid_to='09.09.9999'.

In second one it is `LEFT JOIN` with AND condition.

```
it.valid_to ='09.09.9999'
AND pd.valid_to   ='09.09.9999'
```

So it is possible that there are records in DB_LINK_PROD_ENV having valid_to='09.09.9999' but `NO` any record in DB_LINK_TEST_ENV with valid_to='09.09.9999'.

 So when you will perform MINUS in first query, it will show record present in DB_LINK_PROD_ENV. But in second query AND condition will fail to give you any record.